# Codeigniter: unable to upload image (You did not select a file to upload)

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3, image-upload

When I try to upload a image to my uploads folder i get the following error:

> Array ( [error] =>
>   You did not select a file to upload.)

My View:

```
<form action="<?=base_url('create_public_profile_job') ?>" class="create-profile-form" method="POST">
     <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20000" />
     <button type="submit" class="create-profile-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My Controller

```
public function create_public_profile_job()
{ 
    if(isset($_POST['userfile']))
    {
            $this->User_model->do_upload($_POST['userfile']);
    }
}
```

My Model

```
public function do_upload($userfile)
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $config['upload_path']          = 'assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 1000000;
    $config['max_width']            = 10240000;
    $config['max_height']           = 7680000;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($userfile))
    {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($userfile);
            print_r($error);
    }
    else
    {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            print_r($data);
    }
}
```

The Model part is from the Codeigniter userguide https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Don't really know where the issue is, because I pass the image through all functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what my problem was. Or better problems.

My first Problem was that I had to add to my form tag: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as others already pointed out in the comments

My second problem was that I had to add in my autoload.php file `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database',.., 'upload');`

Last but not least I changed `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` to `$this->upload->initialize($config);`
Somehow the configuration was not able to initialize correctly, so this fixed my last problem.

Answer (score 0):

change view to

```
<form action="<?=base_url('create_public_profile_job') ?>" class="create- 
profile-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20000" />
     <button type="submit" class="create-profile-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Technically it's working. The Image is now send over my form, but I still can't upload my image. I changed my Controller so now it's: if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])) instead of $_POST. But now i get the following errors:
Msg: Illegal offset type in isset or empty
and                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Msg: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: You must check one of the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag to upload the data through the forms.